# Jasper Problems

Tags: raspbian, modules

I trying to run the [Jasper Platform](http://jasperproject.github.io/) which is an open source platform for voice-controlled applications. It enables anyone with a Raspberry Pi to create always on, Siri-like applications with just a few lines of code.

Everytime I run boot.sh from jasper/boot, I get this error message...

```
File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
from conversation import Conversation
File "/home/pi/jasper/client/conversation.py", line 1, in <module>
from notifier import Notifier
File "/home/pi/jasper/client/notifier.py", line 2, in <module>
from modules import Gmail
File "/home/pi/jasper/client/modules/Gmail.py", line 5, in <module>
from app_utils import *
File "/home/pi/jasper/client/modules/app_utils.py", line 5, in <module>
import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

I am not really a dev and just trying out Jasper. What is the correct way to start Jasper?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using [this Jasper](http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/)?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Yes I am

Comment: Silly question, but did you follow all of the installation instructions provided at http://jasperproject.github.io/documentation/software/

Comment: Is this everything that is output?  Looking at the source code boot.sh runs boot.py which appears to output starting messages.  Do you get those messages?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn I did follow all the instructions and yes there are some starting message's (off the top of my head: Starting dictionary, etc).